# Why this is true?$\exists x \in U, [P(x) \land Q(x)] \Leftrightarrow [(\exists x \in U, P(x)) \land (\exists x \in U, Q(x))]$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$$ 
  [\exists x \in U, P(x) \land Q(x)]   \Leftrightarrow [(\exists x \in U, P(x)) \land (\exists x \in U, Q(x))]
$$

Comment: The LHS implies the RHS, but not the other way around. The equivalence does not hold.

Comment: but i don't know how to prove or disprove it

Comment: To disprove it you need to find an interpretation that makes the statement false. In view of my comment above, it suffices to find unary predicates $P$ and $Q$ defined over a universe such that the RHS is true, but the LHS is not.

Comment: thx for your editing

Comment: Your question is a subquestion of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652415/mixing-and-distributing-qualifiers-forall-x-exists-x) one.

Comment: There is a tasty vegetable, and there is a vegetable that is a cauliflower. That certainly doesn't mean that there is a vegetable that is a tasty cauliflower.

Answer (score 4):

This is false, its like saying there is someone who is the president of America and there is someone who is president of France, but to say there is someone who is president of both America and France is quite a different thing.